# Proving that $k[x,y,z]/(xz - (y^2 + 1))$ is a normal ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x,y,z]$ be the polynomial ring in indeterminates $x,y,z$. Define the quotient ring $$R = k[x,y,z]/(xz - (y^2 + 1)).$$

I want to prove that $R$ is a normal ring. My definition of a normal ring is:

A ring $R$ is a normal ring if $R$ is an integral domain that is integrally closed in $\operatorname{frac}(R).$

I think I should show that $R = k(x)[y] \cap k(z)[y]$ in $\operatorname{frac}(R)$, but how can I do this?

Also,I know how to show that a polynomial ring say $k[x],$ in one determinant (where $k$ is a field) is a normal ring, but I do not know how to prove that this quotient ring $R$ is a normal ring.

Also, it is not very clear to me what will be the correct field of fraction of this ring.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can replace x with u+v, and z with u-v. Then the relation becomes u^2=v^2+y^2+1. Hence u is algebraically related to the field k(v,y). The fraction field is L=k(v,y)(u). It is enough to show that k[u,v,y] is the integral closure of k[v,y] in L. We can do it as follows: take arbitrary element z=p+qu in L, where p and q are in k(v,y) (since degree(u)=2). If it is algebraically related to k[v,y], then trace(z)=2p, norm(z)=p^2-q^2(v^2+y^2+1) are both in k[v,y]. It follows that both p and q are polynomials in k[v,y].

Comment: How can you show that p and q are polynomials if char(k)=2?